# How many international tourist deaths are terrorism related?

Tags: safety, statistics

Worldwide, over the past couple of decades (maybe since October 9 1995 if you need to be exact), how many deaths of international tourists are terrorism-related?

Either absolute numbers (eg 12,345 people total), or relative (eg 12 deaths per 100,000 tourists, or alternatively 1.2% of all international tourist deaths) is acceptable.

I tried doing a google search for "terrorism risk international tourism", but only came across papers researching the impact of terrorism on tourism.

Comment: Not exactly the information you are asking for, but this list of [US Citizen Deaths Overseas](http://www.travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/statistics/deaths.html) is somewhat related. It doesn't single out tourist vs other reasons for travel (military probably the largest group), doesn't claim to be a complete list, and is only for US Citizens, but it may interest you.

Comment: Many orders of magnitude fewer than the number of tourist deaths from travelling by car, so probably not something to worry about! [Lots of statistics and citations available here](http://www.globalresearch.ca/the-terrorism-statistics-every-american-needs-to-hear/5382818) (amongst others)

Comment: It is no an exact answer because a) Is he a tourist or resident? b)Is tourist alive or not? c) Does terroists count as tourists?

Comment: I suspect this is impossible to answer, you'd have to define tourist (which I guess you could, but what about business travelers or travelers who wouldn't call themselves tourists). But you'd also have to define terrorism and that's much harder and when you get down to adding up numbers (which you'll have to) I think many people would disagree with each others interpretations. If there's a formal definition of terrorism it might be possible.

Comment: I found the [Global Terrorism Index](http://www.visionofhumanity.org/#/page/our-gti-findings) which both defines terrorism (although you could argue with their definition) and provides yearly numbers. I've no idea if it would be possible to cross-reference tourist deaths but you could probably come up with a guess/estimate. I don't have time to dig into the report now.

Comment: I suspect it's several orders of magnitude lower than the numbers you quote.  I'd be surprised if it's even approaching 100 per year worldwide.

Comment: The answer to this question, of course, depends on the (entirely subjective) definition of "terrorism."